# VB.Net Linq Datatable Exists

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I would like to use Linq instead of below function :

```
Friend Function IsCollectionInTable2(ByVal apps As DataTable, ByVal collectionId As String) As Boolean
    For Each row As DataRow In apps.Rows
        If row("CollectionId").ToString = collectionId Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

The best I can do is below:

```
Friend Function IsCollectionInTable(ByVal apps As DataTable, ByVal collectionId As String) As Boolean
    Return (From row In apps.AsEnumerable()
             Where (row.Field(Of String)("CollectionId") = collectionId)
             Select row.Field(Of String)("CollectionId")).Count > 0
End Function
```

I would like to use Exists or Any in above function. Performance could be an issue,

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that seems to work :

```
Return (From row In apps.AsEnumerable()
        Where row.Field(Of String)("CollectionId") = collectionId).Any()
```

I hope this is as fast as :

```
For Each row As DataRow In apps.Rows
If row("CollectionId").ToString = collectionId Then Return True
Next
Return False
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (sorry my VB is poor)

```
    Dim expression As String
    expression = string.Format("CollectionId = '{0}'", collectionId)
    ' Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.
    return apps.Select(expression).Count > 0
```

Comment: Better than my example but still it have to read all rows. I would like to use Exists or Any so that it can return as soon as possible.